# How to enable UTF-8 in URL on form submit (Joomla, PHP, Apache)

Tags: php, html, forms, apache, joomla

A very easy (I hope) question this time:

I have a form inside a custom Joomla Component which uses `GET` to submit.

The URL ends up being like this:

> page?param1%5B%5D=G&param2%5B%5D=F&param3=10&param4=45%2C170

While it could be (and I want it to be this way):

> page?param1[]=G&param2[]=F&param3=10&param4=45,170

This last one is accepted by the server and script but every time I submit the form it redirects to that first one.

I think it's a Joomla thing but it could just as well be a PHP or Apache thing.

Anyone knows about this behavior?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to achieve? How does the redirection URL bothers you?

Comment: As the question says: I want to make a human (noob) readable URL that people can tweak easily.

Let's say there is a parameter called price which looks like '30,100' (start and end price). I want them to be able to understand what it says and change it to 40,100 for example without having to build something that lets them tweak each and every parameter just to get a URL.

Comment: People don't look in URL nowadays, only geeks unfortunately. But if you want to achieve this anyway, you can use urldecode() function, if it's PHP, or encodeURIComponent(), if it's JS. Just pass your URL to one of these functions before redirecting and it should be good.